# No option to Create Azure AKS cluster with Azure container registry (ACR) using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-aks

I want to create an Azure AKS cluster with Azure container registry integrated with it. I can create this manually using Azure portal. However, I do not see any such option via [ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerservice/managedclusters).

Is this integration not supported yet in ARM templates or have I missed it? Kindly help me out.

[image]

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem or any more questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You could review the Azure generated ARM template with your desired configuration**

**Scenario 1** - You're creating the AKS cluster

1. At the Review + create section
2. Click on *Download a template for automation*
3. It will display the generated template given your specific configurations
   [image: Create AKS from Az Portal]

**Scenario 2** - You already created the AKS cluster

1. Open the Resource Group where you deployed the AKS
2. Click on Deployments
3. Select your specific Deployment (A new tab will open, click on Template)
   [image: az deployments]

In conclusion, you could use the portal to either initiate or deploy the AKS with your desired configurations. Thereafter, just check out the generated ARM template for guidance.